# Computer connects to ethernet when I'm only using wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

I connect my computer through a wireless connection and use a vpn (private internet access).  Whenever I start my computer it connects to the wifi and I have internet.  Then however whenever my vpn loads up and connects my computer automatically connects to an ethernet connection even though there is no ethernet cable plugged in, and I lose internet.  I then have to disable that connection which disconnects my vpn.  Then next time I start up my computer it all happens over again.  Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What is the name of the Ethernet connection? Some VPN's install a network adapter that you may think looks like an Ethernet connection but actually is the VPN itself. Screenshots and possibly the name of the VPN would help too.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Windows or OS X on an Apple computer?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to the VPN, it will create different connections each time you connect so that your own network remains hidden. This ensures that your information is not being exposed. However, this should not be disabling your internet connection. While connected to the VPN if you're unable to browser this is normally due to the dns or a port being restricted.

This could also be a route issue. You would want to speak with your VPN provider.